# How to use ListPlay and PlayRange in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, sound

The following correctly produces a click sound:

```
samples = 8000;
half = 4000;
timeconstant = 100;
list = RotateRight[Table[Exp[-t/timeconstant], {t, 0, samples - 1}], half] // N;
ListPlay[list, PlayRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

But any of the three following variations on PlayRange produce three clicks.

```
ListPlay[list, PlayRange -> All]

ListPlay[list, PlayRange -> Automatic]

ListPlay[list]
```

This is incorrect.

I could just use the working variant, but if I use it inside a Manipulate,

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlay[list, PlayRange -> {-1., 1.}]
 , {x, 0, 1}]
```

I get the obviously incorrect error message:

"Value of PlayRange -> {-1.,1.} is not a list of two machine-sized real numbers."

I realize these are probably bugs, and I have notified Wolfram, but I wonder if any experts here have any insight or workarounds. My need is urgent.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping `ListPlay` with `Evaluate` we get the expected output (v 9.0.1.0 Windows 8 x64):

```
Manipulate[Evaluate@ListPlay[list, PlayRange -> {-1., 1.}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Based on OP's comment below, the following *"did it"*:

```
Manipulate[ControlActive[x,
             EmitSound[Sound[SampledSoundList[Clip[list, {-1., 1}], 8000]]]; x], 
 {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: That is excellent, but I need to emit the sound. Neither of these works:

  Manipulate[
 EmitSound[Evaluate@ListPlay[list, PlayRange -> {-1., 1.}]], {x, 0, 1}]

Manipulate[
 Evaluate@EmitSound[ListPlay[list, PlayRange -> {-1., 1.}]], {x, 0,  1} , TrackedSymbols :> {x}]

Comment: @abwatson, why not use `Play` button in the content area of `Manipulate[Evaluate@ListPlay[list, PlayRange -> {-1., 1.}], {x, 0, 1}]` to emit the click sound? How is `x` related to the content displayed?

Comment: I would rather that the user not have to do anything extra (click on play) to produce the sound. Manipulate does not usually require such extra steps. The x has no effect in this example. It was just there to cause evaluation after user action. In my real use, I am presenting two clicks with a variable delay between them, to illustrate sound localization.The user varies the delay and listens to the result.

Comment: @abwatson, does this give something close to what you need `Manipulate[ControlActive[x, EmitSound[ Sound[ SampledSoundList[Clip[list, {-1., 1}], 8000]]]; 
  x], {x, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: Thanks! That did it, though I confess I do not understand why. I will have to study ControlActive.